# UITableView [or UICollectionView] as inputView performance problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview

I'm trying to use a UITableView as an inputView for a UITextView. Everything works, however the table view scroll performance reminds me of Android devices (30 fps, lagging).
I've made some tests with a clean project adding the same UITableView directly below the textView and the scroll goes smooth.

Also, I've profiled the two scenarios with Instruments. I'm not an expert with Instruments, but it seems that when the table view is used as an inputView, it takes twice the time to execute the method:

`- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds;`

[I've uploaded a clean project](https://db.tt/L8FoMOog) with the code demoing the issue.

Everything was performed on an iPhone 5 and on an iPad Mini Retina.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!